# JEditorPane.setPage() method works only once during runtime

Tags: java, html, swing, user-input, jeditorpane

I am currently working on a project that allows the user to input a url, such as http://www.google.com and the user is able to edit the html code of the page.  So far I save the edited file as an html document when the JTextArea has a key released. Here is the source code that I use:

```
String s = jTextArea1.getText();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("HTML.htm")));
ps.print(s);
ps.close();

this.resetPage();
```

The last line of code calls this bit of source code (this is actually where I attempt to update the page with the user's input:

```
File f = new File("HTML.htm");
URL u =f.toURI().toURL();
jEditorPane1.setPage(u);
```

All the proper exceptions are caught.  It updates the text on the page once.  All the images are blank (which I expected because the paths were all local) but that should have no real effect on the other html in the document.

When I open the HTML.htm file in notepad++ the file IS being updated but the jEditorPane is not getting updated with the new html script.

Also, the JEditorPane has its Editable vale set to false.

When I open the file in Chrome, it gets the fully updated script.

Answer (score 2):

From the JEditorPane setPage(URL) API description:

*To force a document reload it is necessary to clear the stream description property of the document. The following code shows how this can be done:*

```
Document doc = jEditorPane.getDocument();
doc.putProperty(Document.StreamDescriptionProperty, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

File f = new File("HTML.htm");
    URL u =f.toURI().toURL();
    jEditorPane1.setPage(u);
    jEditorPane1.updateUI();